# Substituir valor undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro do meu dashboard, o usuário faz um filtro que vai ao banco e retorna um objeto JavaScript por meio de uma requisição assíncrona e a extensão do array pode variar, sendo que pode ter um `length` de 1 até 3, sempre!

Então, às vezes quando o usuário faz o filtro, no meu console retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ao clicar no log, neste exemplo, a chave 2 do array é grifada, indicando que este é o indefinido. Chequei no banco de dados e tudo mais e é isso mesmo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então para isso procurei no fórum sobre o assunto e construí esta função que esta sendo usada como na imagem acima:

```
function tratarValorIndefinido(vl){
    if(typeof(vl)  === "undefined"){
        vl ="S/ HISTÓRICO";
    }
};
```

Só que ao invés de carimbar o "S/ HISTÓRICO", ele está retornando `undefined`.

Onde estou errando?

***COMO TRAGO ATUALMENTE O OBJ.

```
var dataBar = {
    labels: [dataChart[0]['mesReferencia'],dataChart[1]['mesReferencia'],dataChart[2]['mesReferencia']], 
    datasets: [{
        label: "CPF's Enviados", 
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.8)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.9)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.9)",
        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,51,90,1)",
        data: [dataChart[0]['cpfsEnviados'],dataChart[1]['cpfsEnviados'],dataChart[2]['cpfsEnviados']]
    },
```

**estrutura do `data[0]`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assim fica mais simples e deve resolver o problema: `function tratarValorIndefinido(vl){ return vl || "S/ HISTÓRICO"; }`

Comment: `typeof(vl)` é sintaxe errada. Podes mostrar como estás a usar `tratarValorIndefinido` para podermos ajudar com o código correto?

Comment: Corrigindo: o que está indefinido não é o mesReferencia e sim o elemento 2 inteiro do array que você está tentando acessar. O que resolveria o problema seria:

    dataChart[2] ? dataChart[2]["mesReferencia"]: "S/HISTÓRICO"

Comment: @jvbarsou , tente a mesma condição sem utilizar aspas [ typeof(v1) === undefined  ], pois se colocar dentro de aspas fica como se fosse uma string "qualquer texto" a ser comparado.

Answer (score 2):

Toda função em Javascript que não declara um retorno com a palavra-chave `return`, retorna `undefined` por padrão.

Creio que falta apenas isso. `return vl;` ao final da função deve resolver o seu problema. Ou então, `return "S/ HISTÓRICO"` direto.

Comment: Seguindo seu exemplo, ele não altera nem para undefined o valor

Comment: @jvbarsou é injusto corrigires respostas sem mostrares onde e como usas o teu código. Clica em `editar` na pergunta para mostrares como estás a usar esse código.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugeriria para você percorrer a própria lista e caso encontre `undefined` alterar o valor direto no objeto. Um exemplo da lista pode ser:

```
[
 {id: 1, mesReferencia: "Jan"},
 {id: 2, mesReferencia: undefined}
];
```

E usar o [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para modificar o valor:

```
arrayDeObjetos.forEach(function(item) {
  if (typeof item.mesReferencia === "undefined") item.mesReferencia = "S/ HISTÓRICO";
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var itens = [
 {id: 1, mesReferencia: "Jan"},
 {id: 2, mesReferencia: undefined}
];

itens.forEach(function(item) {
  if (typeof item.mesReferencia === "undefined") item.mesReferencia = "S/ HISTÓRICO";
});
  
console.log(itens);
```

Comment: no caso, pode ser colocado como no exemplo da imagem? Editei o código para mostrar como é trazido atualmente.

Comment: Acabei de inserir @lucas

Comment: vou editar na resposta a estrutura